# How can I selectively choose train and test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

When you do cross_validation.train_test_split(features,labels,test_size), it is one data set that is automatically being split into training and testing data by cross_validation but how can you train and test two separate sets of data? So if the training data is in one file and the testing data is in another file, and you want to first train the data using the train file and then test using the test file how can you do that? Because cross_validation only takes one set of data and splits it into train and test automatically.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

When there is just one split there is no **cross** validation, you just literally train on one dataset and check your accuracy (or other metric) on test one, without the use of CV (since, as said before - there is no such tring as CV for a single split). This is the exact oposite of what CV is for. CV has been introduced **because** single split is not enough for valid estimation of test **for small dataset**.